# ownerDocument.defaultView is null ie8 bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am using several components of bootstrap in my project, two of the components "accordion" and "modal" however, are not working in IE8 at all. According to bootstrap's documentation it supports IE8 and I am assuming that accordion and modal should work too.

- Bootstrap version - 3.1.0
- jQuery version - 1.11.0

**Accordion Code -**

```
     <div class='accordion-container'>
         <div class='panel-group' id='accordion'>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div id="panal_9" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" class="panel-heading" style="">
                   <h4 class="panel-title">Class 9</h4>
               </div>
               <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <div class="list-group">
                           <ul class="list-unstyled">
                              <li data-class="1" data-subject="2">English</li> 
                              <li data-class="1" data-subject="1">Math</li>
                              <li data-class="1" data-subject="6">Social Science</li>
                           </ul> 
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Problem -**

Clicking the accordion title throws an error on IE8 - `'ownerDocument.defaultView' is null or not an object`

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, So I hope it's not still an issue, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this I thought I'd post my solution.

By chance are you using Holder from http://imsky.co?

Holder defines window.getComputedStyle if it doesn't exist. Which it doesn't in IE8.

jQuery checks for window.getComputedStyle existence. If it exists jQuery jumps into IE8 not safe code. If window.getComputedStyle doesn't exist everything works fine.

My fix was to edit holder.js.

This line:

```
(window.getComputedStyle = function (e) { return this.el = e, this.getPropertyValue = function (t) { var n = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g; return t == "float" && (t = "styleFloat"), n.test(t) && (t = t.replace(n, function () { return arguments[2].toUpperCase() })), e.currentStyle[t] ? e.currentStyle[t] : null }, this })
```

is the problem.

I changed the getComputedStyle check to:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyleHolder = window.getComputedStyle;
} else {
    (window.getComputedStyleHolder = function (e) { return this.el = e, this.getPropertyValue = function (t) { var n = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g; return t == "float" && (t = "styleFloat"), n.test(t) && (t = t.replace(n, function () { return arguments[2].toUpperCase() })), e.currentStyle[t] ? e.currentStyle[t] : null }, this })
}
```

Then I updated every other reference to window.getComputedStyle in holder.js to window.getComputedStyleHolder